# How to write XML with file size limitation?

Tags: java, xml, limit, filesize

I am dealing with a task to create xml files dynamically but each xml file has file limit of 6 MB. When creating/filling the xml file, I am constantly iterating on "Item" entities in my DB and I need to serialize them like the structure below. That below is example and the xml has more complex structure, I'd prefer not to use StringBuilder if possible. How can I check the size of the xml file dynamically and create a second file before exceeding the limit? Any hints would be appreciated!

```
<Root>
    <ItemList>
        <Item></Item>
        <Item></Item>
        <Item></Item>
    </ItemList>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could count the symbols everytime you add something. Depending on the used encoding, you know the size of each symbol.

I admit, it is an ugly solution. But is is sunday and my brain won't come up with somthing nicer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try **CountingOutputStream**, see the [API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html).

Estimate the maximum length of your `<Item>` element.

After writing each item check the currently written size and check, if the remaining bytes are sufficient for one more item and for the remainder (`</ItemList>`, `</Root>`, white spaces, end-of-line chars).